# Layout on a layout, center background image of top layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok, I wanna do something rather complex.

I want to put a drawable in the first linear layout, then I wanna put another drawable in a second layout on top of the first layout and I want it to be centered. Reason I'm doing this is so that the icon will not stretch when it switches to landscape. This is what I have so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/default1"

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/icon1" android:layout_gravity="center"
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The icon in the second layout sticks to the top of the screen and is not centered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change all `fill_parent` to `wrap_content`